# Create new data set that meets all of 4 conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, conditional-statements

I would like to create a new dataset where the following four conditions are all met.

```
rowSums(is.na(UNCA[,11:23]))<12

rowSums(is.na(UNCA[,27:39]))<12

rowSums(is.na(UNCA[,40:52]))<12

rowSums(is.na(UNCA[,53:65]))<12
```

Thanks!

Comment: I still don't quite understand your intention. Please put some dummy data, so we can get a grip with your problem. Would you be so kind to explain what does `dataset` imply? A `data.frame` or a `vector`? Or something else?
@Shane apparently got it, but I don't get what's the bit...

Comment: It looks like you are checking for the existence of values that aren't `NA`. `any(!is.na(UNCA[,rows]))` may be clearer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Then use the `&` operator:

```
UNCA.new <- UNCA[rowSums(is.na(UNCA[,11:23])) < 12 & 
                 rowSums(is.na(UNCA[,27:39])) < 12 & 
                 rowSums(is.na(UNCA[,40:52])) < 12 &  
                 rowSums(is.na(UNCA[,53:65])) < 12, ]
```

A single `&` is a vectorized function, while a double `&&` is unary (typically used in an `if` statement, for instance).