# Subsetting a dataframe for a specified month and year in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a dataframe where the second column is a date in m/d/y format. There are 4 main column: name, date, time_taken, homequeue

I want to create subsets for particular month of one year (eg. 11/11, 12/11 etc)which i will use to calculate the total timetaken by people of particular homequeue who work from 4/1/2020 to 4/7/2020

I tried the code suggested in this answer: subset a data.frame with multiple conditions ([Subsetting a dataframe for a specified month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407622/subsetting-a-dataframe-for-a-specified-month-and-year))

and it is not working for me. Please check image for dataset:
[utilization data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE728.jpg)
**

```html
df <- read.csv('Rm_2020-04-20 copy.csv')

combo <- subset(df, home_queue == 'Brand Effects', format.Date(date, "%m") == "04" & format.Date(date, "%Y") == "20")
```

**

but it returns an empty subset with error message

**Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x) : 'origin' must be supplied**

I am using R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) on Mac , thanks in adavance. I am new to the stackoverflow and learning R.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

The OP is relatively unclear, so this answer must be speculative. But it appears that what is missing is the conversion of your `date` values to POSIXct values. This conversion can be achieved thus:

Let's assume you have data similar to this:

```
my.data <- read.csv(text = '
          Date,      Var2,  Var3
                    05/10/2011,    AK,     aa
                    06/15/2011,    AK,     bb
                    07/21/2011,    OH,     cc
                    NA,    OH,     dd
                    05/13/2012,    PA,     ee
                    07/22/2012,    AL,     ff
                    03/28/2013,    NY,     gg
                    ', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = 'NA', strip.white = TRUE)
```

At this point your dates are, for R, just character strings, as can be seen from calling `str`:

```
str(my.data)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Date: chr  "05/10/2011" "06/15/2011" "07/21/2011" NA ...
 $ Var2: chr  "AK" "AK" "OH" "OH" ...
 $ Var3: chr  "aa" "bb" "cc" "dd" ...
```

To make R recognize the dates as dates proper, use `as.POSIXct`:

```
my.data$my_Date <- as.POSIXct(my.data$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Now you can subset, for example, on May:

```
my.data[format.Date(my.data$my_Date, "%m")=="05" &
      !is.na(my.data$my_Date),]

        Date Var2 Var3    my_Date
1 05/10/2011   AK   aa 2011-05-10
5 05/13/2012   PA   ee 2012-05-13
```

Or, select May of one particular year, e.g., 2012:

```
my.data[format.Date(my.data$my_Date, "%Y")=="2012" & 
          format.Date(my.data$my_Date, "%m")=="05" &
          !is.na(my.data$my_Date),]

        Date Var2 Var3    my_Date
5 05/13/2012   PA   ee 2012-05-13
```