# How can I subset a dataset to a specific year?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, subset

I have a dataset (Crime) with 6,847,944 observations. I am trying to downsize this data to only those occurring in the relevant year of 2016. The dates can be found in the "Date" column.  I have tried all of the following for code:

```
#change dates to proper format#
Crime$Date = as.Date(Crime$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y")

#filter crimes to 2016#
```

ATTEMPT 1: `Crime16 = subset(Crime$Date = as.Date("2016"))`

RESULT 1: `Error: unexpected '=' in "Crime16 = subset(Crime$Date ="`

ATTEMPT 2: `Crimes_2016 <- Crime[year(Date)==2016,]`

RESULT 2: `Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) : do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”`

ATTEMPT 3: `Crimes_2016 = subset(Crime, Date >=2016/1/1 & Date <= 2016/31/12)`

RESULT 3: Creates data frame, but contains no observations.

ATTEMPT 4: `morecrimes = subset(Crime, Date == 2016)`

RESULT 4: Creates data frame, but contains no observations.

ATTEMPT 5: `Crimes.2016 = selectByDate(Crime$Date = 2016)`

RESULT 5: `Error: unexpected '=' in "Crimes.2016 = selectByDate(Crime$Date ="`

Comment: This is R, what exactly is the environment you are working with? A dataframe exists in pandas, etc. as well.

Comment: I am using R. I just misspoke.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subsetting a dataframe for a specified month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407622/subsetting-a-dataframe-for-a-specified-month-and-year)

Answer (score 0):

Without a proper reproducible example dataset I cannot be sure of what you are after but... taking the following dataframe as a test:

```
x <- data.frame(
  "Date" = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2015-05-12", "2016-06-16"), format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
  "Crime" = LETTERS[1:3])
```

Which gives:

```
> x
        Date Crime
1 2016-01-01     A
2 2015-05-12     B
3 2016-06-16     C
```

This can be subset making a logical vector, generated by `format(x$Date, "%Y") == "2016"` where I change the date format to just year, and using that in a linear search of the data.frame to return the rows where the elements of the logical vector are "`TRUE`" as such:

```
> x[format(x$Date, "%Y") == "2016", ]
        Date Crime
1 2016-01-01     A
3 2016-06-16     C

x[format(x$Date, "%Y") == "2016", ]
```

Giving:

```
> x[format(x$Date, "%Y") == "2016", ]
        Date Crime
1 2016-01-01     A
3 2016-06-16     C
```

Alternatively you could use the dplyr function `filter()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
# Route 1. Implement filter() the base R way
filter(x, format(x$Date, "%Y") == "2016")
# Route 2. Use filter() the tidyverse way
x %>% filter(format(x$Date, "%Y") == "2016")
```